# Returning an address of a character from a function in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

I'm trying to write a program that will take a string as an input and a character to find in that string . A function should then return the address of that particular character . The logic seems to be correct as far as i know but for some reason when i call the function it returns the rest of the string after the target character rather than the address of the character. E.g : if i enter "Hello" and enter "e" as the target , the function will return "llo". Any help / explanation would be appreciated.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cstring>

char *mystrrchr (char *s, char c)
{
    char *charptr;
    for(int i = 0;i<strlen(s)-1;i++)
    {
        if(s[i] == c)
        {
            charptr = &s[i];
        }
    }
    return charptr;
    }
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    char *string = new char[100];
    char a;
    cout<<"Enter string : ";
    cin.getline(string,100);
    cout<<"Enter character to find in string : ";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"The adress of the last occurence of the character entered is : "<<mystrrchr(string,a)<<endl;

}
```

Comment: Don't calculate `strlen` in a loop, it will scan the string each iteration.

Comment: `std::string str; cin >> str; std::const_iterator find_it = std::find(str.begin(), str.end(), mychar); if (find_it == str.end()) std::cout << "Cannot find " << mychar << "\n"; else std::cout << mychar << " is at address " << &*find_it;`

Comment: @NeilKirk Use `std::string`, and don't calculate the string length at all.  (Otherwise, of course: `std::find(s, s + std::strlen(s), c)` is the simplest solution.

Comment: @NeilKirk can you explain why i can't use it? How else can i condition the loop to check through the whole string? Thank you!

Comment: What compiler and what settings are you using?

Comment: `for(size_t i = 0, i_end = strlen(s)-1; i != i_end; i++)` You sure you want the -1 though? That will skip the last character.

Comment: Aha correction to my code: `static_cast<const void*>(&*find_it);`

Comment: for(int i = 0;i<strlen(s)-1;i++)    is   for (char * c = s; *c; ++c)

Comment: ...<<mystrrchr(string,a)<<endl  should be ...<< (int)(mystrrchr(string,a))<<endl  if you want to see the char * as an address rather than as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're printing a `char*`.  The default behavior is to print it as a C-style null-terminated string, rather than as an address.  Try instead:

```
... << static_cast<const void*>(mystrrchr(string,a))
```

Comment: But it should still print from 'e' and not from 'l' in the OPs program.

Comment: It worked when i did that but can you please tell me why the way i did it doesn't work?
Thanks!

Comment: @KareemYoussef: because you were printing from the return value to the end of the string, as a string. But you wanted to print the address.  So you must tell the computer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work for me - your function returns a pointer the correct character.

There were a couple of things to clear up to make it work properly though:

I added a static cast to void*:

```
static_cast<void*>(found))
```

to the output (so it outputs the address) and then I output the substring on the next line.

This is because `cout` expects a `c_string` when passed a pointer to a char (`char*`) so when you pass it the return from  `mystrrchr`, it prints the string.
In order to get it to print the address, we needed to cast it to another type of pointer (for all other pointers the behaviour is to print the address).

I also fixed:
`main` now returns `int` as `void main(){}` is not valid in C++:

```
prog.cpp:19:11: error: ‘::main’ must return ‘int’
```

<s>changed `mystrrchr` to only calculate the length of the string once.</s>
changed the for loop in `mystrrch` so that the length of string does not need to be calculated, instead it loops while the null terminator of the string has not been reached.

See it here: http://ideone.com/TmTwFM
Input:

```
hello
e
```

output:

```
The address of the last occurence of the character entered is : 0x96fd009
The string from the last occurence of the character entered is : ello
```

updated code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

char *mystrrchr (char *s, char c)
{
    char *charptr;
    for(int i = 0; s[i]; i++)
    {
        if(s[i] == c){
            charptr = &s[i];}
    }
    return charptr;
}

int main()
{
    char *string = new char[100];
    char a;
    cout<<"Enter string : ";
    cin.getline(string,100);
    cout<<"\nEnter character to find in string : ";
    cin>>a;

    char* found = mystrrchr(string,a);

    cout<<"\nThe address of the last occurence of the character entered is : "<<static_cast<void*>(found)<<
          "\nThe string from the last occurence of the character entered is : "<<found<<endl;

}
```

Comment: The static cast works but why doesn't the way i do it work? The function is supposed to return the address so how come when i try to print it , it returns the rest of the string?

Comment: I edited the first main paragraph to explain it better (starting with "`cout` expects") I hope this helps

Comment: The 2 programs are essentially the same, but why does Kareems program print 'llo' and yours 'ello'

Comment: Once I fixed the `void main()` issue, Kareem's program printed "ello" for me.

Comment: @Baldrickk, interesting case of undefined behaviour!

Comment: @Surt I must be missing the UB... To be honest, I don't see why @kareem was only getting `"llo"` as output. Though his use of `void main` suggests the use of an old compiler, I don't think that that should change anything.

Comment: @Baldrickk, neither do I, which was why I asked for the compiler version and settings. None of the compilers I checked at godbolt.org accepted 'void main' but I think old versions of VS did.

Comment: I was thinking of _Turbo C++_ myself as an example I believe it is non-standards compliant (being around beforehand).  I think VS accepts it because it uses the same compiler for `C` and `C++` programs, but don't see why VS would give the 'wrong' output. I've never used Turbo C++

Answer (score 0):

> E.g : if i enter "Hello" and enter "e" as the target , the function will return "llo"

No. You want the function to return the address of a particular character, and that is exactly what it does.

The problem is with your output. C-style strings, which are represented by a pointer to their first character, are terminated by a null-character. `std::cout` interprets the result of your function as a C-style string and outputs it all the way to the end.

If you want to output the address, you should cast the result to `void *`.

```
static_cast<void*>(ptr);
```

As a side note, you should not use `strlen` in a loop, as it will iterate the entire string for every iteration. For a string such as "hello" that might not be an issue, but for longer strings it becomes a problem quite fast.

Instead, use `strlen` outside the loop, like so:

```
int len = strlen(str);
for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to why your program prints the string and not the address is that [ostream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator-free/) overloads 'char *', making it necessary to cast it to 'void *'.